# How to ETL CLOB data type using DataStage

Tags: clob, datastage

I have a table to be be fetched, One of the column in particular table contains HTML data stored as a CLOB, The length is '1048576'
In my ETL job, I have replaced CLOB with LongVarChar of same size (1048576) as CLOB is not defined in data Stage but the job is not working (There is no error but it stays in running stage for long without moving a single row).

Can anyone recommend solution for similar issue faced? Thanks!